# How to split table to chunks and select AVG of each chunk

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

MySQL 5.7

I have a table without primary key (used for statistics):

```
|value|      date|
|-----+----------|
|    1|13-03-2019|
|    2|12-03-2019|
|    3|16-03-2019|
|    4|16-03-2019|
|    5|16-03-2019|
|    6|16-03-2019|
```

How can I split table to ***N*** chunks, and select `avg(value)` of each chunk?

Expected result, if table from example above is used with chunk size = 3:

```
|avg_val|
|      2|
|      5|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following solution using a emulated row number ([`ROW_NUMBER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) is supported since MySQL 8.0 so you can't use this):

```
SELECT AVG(value) 
FROM (
    SELECT value, CEIL((@row_number:=@row_number + 1) / 3) AS group_num
    FROM table_name, (SELECT @row_number:=0) rownumber
) t1
GROUP BY t1.group_num;
```

You can use the following solution since MySQL 8.0 (in case you upgrade later and for completeness), using [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number):

```
SELECT AVG(value) 
FROM (
    SELECT value, CEIL(ROW_NUMBER() OVER () / 3) AS group_num
    FROM table_name
) t1
GROUP BY t1.group_num;
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=51de9d591d3ecff8891963908d63c029)

Comment: Thanks! May I ask you one more question about this [query](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b94bf5739bc42d71c9c9b1271174269c)? I want to chunk all the records within last hour to 60 records at all. Instead ***3*** in your answer I use `select()/60` - is that optimal?

Comment: where is the hour (time) stored?

Comment: [Updated fiddle - I used your example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b94bf5739bc42d71c9c9b1271174269c)

Comment: you want to get the average of value per hour or only of the last hour?

Comment: I'd rather make an example: 1000 records at all -> get all records of the last hour (let it be 600 records) -> split these 600 records to 60 chunks (10 records per chunk) -> get average value per chunk.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6c2b84efa2fafd4fa4125bdcfbdf7b6c - i added a greatest so you can define a min chunk size (here 10). the reason why you get three rows is the calculation 3 / 60 = 0.05. so every row is another group_num (no group with more than one item). with greatest you get 10 in this case because 10 > 0.05. with your described amount of data the query should work.